# Shared references with json

Tags: json, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

is it possible to make use of the concept of shared references with JSON as output mode? I read this article http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html), but changing the @Produces on my JAX-RS to JSON forces an endless loop. Basically i want to reduce an object to it`s id:

```
public class Foo {
    private long id;
    private String someText;
    private Bar bar;
}
```

I want this to bind instances of this like so:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "someText": "lorem",
    "bar_id": 9876
}
```

This is what i want to avoid:

```
{
    "id": 1234,
    "someText": "lorem",
    "bar": {
        "id": 9876,
        "anotherText": "ipsum"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

With MOXy as your JSON-binding provider the [shared references](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html%29) post you referenced (from my blog) will work for JSON just as it does for XML.  Since you are using JAX-RS below is an example of configuring MOXy in that environment:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/05/moxy-as-your-jax-rs-json-provider.html

When using `@XmlID`/`@XmlIDREF` it is expected that the object being reference by its ID also exist in the document.  Since this isn't your use case you would be better off using an `XmlAdapter`.  The `XmlAdapter` would have a signature similar to:

```
public class BarAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Integer, Bar> {
    ...
}
```

In the `XmlAdapter` you would be responsible for returning the id from the instance of `Bar` during the marshal, and for returning an instance of `Bar` based on the `id` during an unmarshal.

Comment: Thank you sir. I was stumbling across the provided link earlier, but was not able to implement the custom Application, because i missed the correct moxy jar.